# How can I make a question on topic?

Tags: support, homework-and-exercises

Why is my question "Electrical resistance calculator question" on hold ? What does this mean ? How can i improve it ? Here is the link to my question

[Electrical resistance calculator question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409278/electrical-resistance-calculator-question])

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/)

Answer (score 3):

For general guidance on what "on hold" means, see [What is a “closed”, “on hold”, or “duplicate” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question) at the mother meta.

For specific guidance about why your individual question was put on hold, see the link included in the banner that marks the post as on hold, [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Generally, if an event X happens that affects your posts and it comes accompanied with a banner Y linking to a detailed explainer post Z (in this case, [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)), then jumping on the Ask button without reading the guidance first isn't a particularly useful course of action.